# Write Ant properties to a YAML file

Tags: ant, yaml

I want to have my Ant project output a few properties as YAML file.

For example:

```
<property name="foo" value="aaa"/>
<property name="bar" value="bbb"/>
<property name="baz" value="ccc"/>
```

Is written to output.yml as

```
foo: aaa
bar: bbb
baz: ccc
```

Can anyone suggest a method that doesn't require external tools/libraries?

Comment: Are properties names known and static ? If it is, maybe you could use ant filtering to set curent value for each properties (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/filter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ant has built in JavaScript, which you might try.  See below for an illustration.

This uses [`<scriptdef>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html) to create a task `"props2yaml"` that writes a set of properties to a file.  I've not tried to generalise for characters needing escape sequences, etc.

```
<scriptdef name="props2yaml" language="javascript">
<attribute name="destfile"/>
<element name="propertyset" type="propertyset"/>
<![CDATA[
  var destfile = attributes.get( "destfile" );

  //var properties = project.getProperties( );
  //var prop_names = properties.keySet( ).toArray( ).sort( );

  var properties = elements.get( "propertyset" ).get( 0 ).getProperties( );
  var prop_names = properties.stringPropertyNames( ).toArray( ).sort( );

  var fw = new java.io.FileWriter( destfile );
  for ( var i in prop_names ) {
      fw.write( prop_names[i] + ': "' + properties.get( prop_names[i] ) + '"\n' );
  }
  fw.flush( );
  fw.close( );
]]></scriptdef>

<property name="foo" value="aaa"/>
<property name="bar" value="bbb"/>
<property name="baz" value="ccc"/>

<props2yaml destfile="output.yml">
  <propertyset>
     <propertyref name="foo" />
     <propertyref name="bar" />
     <propertyref name="baz" />
  </propertyset>
</props2yaml>
```

For me the output in this case is:

```
bar: "bbb"
baz: "ccc"
foo: "aaa"
```

You could preserve order by changing the scriptdef as you see fit.

The commented out lines show how to get a full list of all Ant properties in the project.